# How to interpret scored probabilities in machine learning classification algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, probability, text-classification

I am using two Neural networks for two class text classification. I'm getting 90% accuracy on test data. Also using different performance metrics like precision, recall, f-score and confusion matrix to make sure that model is performing as expected.

In the predictive experiment using trained model, I'm fetching probabilities for each prediction.The output looks as follows (Couldn't provide codes it's implemented in Azure ML Studio )

ex:
class (probability) , class 2 (probability) -> predicted class

class 1 (0.99) , class 2 (0.01)     ->  class 1

class 1 (0.53) , class 2 (0.47)     ->  class 1

class 1 (0.2)  , class 2(0.8)       ->  class 2

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzsGX.png)

As per my understanding so far, by looking at the probability we can tell, how confident is the model about its prediction.And 90% accuracy means out 100 records 10 predictions could go wrong.

Now my question is, by looking at probability (confidence) can we tell which bucket the current records falls into 90%(correct prediction) or 10% (wrong prediction)?

What I'm trying to achieve is, to give end your some metric to tell him/her that this prediction is probably wrong, they might want to change it to some other class before using these results.

Comment: I would suggest you to consider ROC score for accuracy metric. This will allow you to know how good is your prediction.

Comment: Hi Tushar, Thanks for the reply... I'm checking different performance metrics like precision, recall, f - score and confusion matrix to make sure that model is performing as expected. And then using trained model for predictions.          While predicting it's assigning a probability to each class and class with most probability is output. Sorry if my question is not clear above.    my question is can we tell by looking at the probability score, whether the prediction is wrong or correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 90% accuracy means out 100 records 10 predictions could go wrong.

It is not exactly like that; accuracy is always (although implicitly) linked to the *specific* test set we have used to measure it: so, 90% means that out of 100 records our classifier indeed misclassified 10 (i.e. there is not "could").

What we *hope* for in machine learning is that the performance of our models in new, unseen data, will be comparable to that of our test set (which, regarding the training of our model, is also unseen). Roughly speaking, provided that our new data come from the same statistical distribution with our training & test sets, it is not an unreasonable expectation.

> What I'm trying to achieve is, to give end your some metric to tell him/her that this prediction is probably wrong, they might want to change it to some other class before using these results.

Intuitively, you should already know the answer to this: interpreting the returned probabilities as confidence (which, at least in principle, is not an invalid interpretation), their values tell you something about how "certain" your model is about its answers: so, what you could do is provide the end users with these probability values; in your example, the case of "Question" with probability 0.97 is indeed qualitatively not the same with the case "Question" with probability ~ 0.50...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what I've observed in some cases by manually checking is that "Question" with 0.97 probability is the wrong prediction ("It is actually Problem"), whereas "Question" with ~0.50 probability is the correct prediction.      In such cases how the end user can act by looking at Probabilities?

Comment: Cannot; you should either accept this as a misclassification risk or try for a better model... (and if the answer was helpful, kindly accept it; answers take up valuable time foe respondents - thanks)